# How to get a specific object from data structure based on Index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am creating a custom `UIPageViewController` which uses a custom setup. The data structure that I have is parsed into the following format:

```
{
    "1.0" =     (
                {
            detail = "Detail 0";
            icon = "Pull to Refresh";
            title = "Item 0";
        },
                {
            detail = "More easily refresh a subscription or playlist.";
            icon = "Pull to Refresh";
            title = "Pull to Refresh";
        }
    );
    "1.1" =     (
                {
            detail = "Create custom stations of your favorite podcasts.";
            icon = Stations;
            title = "Custom Stations";
}
```

When each sub content view controller is created for the Page View I have the index, in the above case it would be 0,1,2. But in 'real life' it could be 0-10 for example.

How do I get the relevant sub dictionary reference from the index?

As an example, if the index was 1, I would want to get the NSDictionary:

```
{
            detail = "More easily refresh a subscription or playlist.";
            icon = "Pull to Refresh";
            title = "Pull to Refresh";
}
```

The part I am unsure about is that within the overall `NSDictionary` of data I have sub `NSArray`'s with different counts of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the keys of the dictionary:

```
NSArray *keys = yourMainDictionary.allKeys;
```

Sort this array by treating the keys as version numbers, since that's what they appear to be (based on your data structure format):

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *key1, NSString *key2) {
    return [key1 compare:key2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Iterate over these keys and add each array's sub-dictionaries to a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *allDictionaries = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    NSArray *subDictionaries = yourMainDictionary[key];
    [allDictionaries addObjectsFromArray:subDictionaries];
}
```

You now have an array of all the sub dictionaries called `allDictionaries`. So, if you have an index, you just access it like any other array, for example:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryWithIndex1 = allDictionaries[1];
```

... should give you:

```
{
    detail = "More easily refresh a subscription or playlist.";
    icon = "Pull to Refresh";
    title = "Pull to Refresh";
}
```